# Charts.js Dynamic Ticks

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

I am using Charts.js and using it to display data over different periods of time, the time periods are based on a user input. I am displaying date labels on the x-axis but sometimes these can range over a period of 0-12 months. I want to dynamically alter this so that if the date range is over 2 months then the labels would show per month? Also the data within that range would be grouped per month. Like when using Google Analytics.

The below is the Javascript I am using to generate the graphs.

```
<script>
            var ctx = document.getElementById('directtraffic').getContext('2d');
            var directtraffic = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'line',
                data: {
                    labels: ["2017-05-01","2017-05-02","2017-05-03","2017-05-04","2017-05-05","2017-05-06","2017-05-07","2017-05-08","2017-05-09","2017-05-10","2017-05-11","2017-05-12","2017-05-13","2017-05-14","2017-05-15","2017-05-16","2017-05-17","2017-05-18","2017-05-19","2017-05-20","2017-05-21","2017-05-22","2017-05-23","2017-05-24","2017-05-25","2017-05-26","2017-05-27","2017-05-28","2017-05-29","2017-05-30","2017-05-31"],
                    datasets: [{
            label: 'Sessions (01/05/2017 - 31/05/2017)',
            data: ["169","278","287","223","252","129","97","246","266","285","262","203","107","121","319","261","336","291","227","110","94","237","263","259","239","172","79","77","111","257","233"],
            responsive: true,
            tooltips: {
                mode: 'index',
                intersect: false,
            },
            legend: {
                display: false,
            },
            hover: {
                mode: 'nearest',
                intersect: true
            },
            backgroundColor: '#5cbae6',
            borderColor: '#5cbae6',
            fill: false
        },{
            label: 'Sessions (01/04/2017 - 30/04/2017)',
            data: ["103","100","261","280","258","250","197","70","94","248","206","239","198","113","113","108","99","248","245","250","225","107","86","244","245","268","299","223","98","119"],
            responsive: true,
            tooltips: {
                mode: 'index',
                intersect: false,
            },
            legend: {
                display: false,
            },
            hover: {
                mode: 'nearest',
                intersect: true
            },
            backgroundColor: '#b6d957',
            borderColor: '#b6d957',
            fill: false
        }]
                },
                options: {
                    animation: false,
                    scales: {
                        xAxes: [{
                            gridLines: {
                                display:false
                            }
                        }],
                        yAxes: [{
                            gridLines: {
                                display:false
                            }  
                        }]
                    }
                }
            });
            </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you will need to add ticks under scales and in you case xAxes. In ticks you can specify the step size. The step size is how much it increments each time. In the step size you can make a call to a function that determines the step size you need. So you could make a function called calcualteStepSize and pass in the dates if it is over over 2 months then return a step size of 1. Below is just some pseudocode

```
ticks: {
        stepSize: calcualteStepSize(data)
       }

function calcualteStepSize(data) {
  if data range is greater than 2 months
    return 1 
  else return some other calculation
}
```